# getInt is not working

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to get an integer from my sqlite database, but getInt() keep crashing. I have been able to use getString() without problems. I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
    public int[] getDayActivities(String date){
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
   int[] chosen = new int[4];

   Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("select * from diary",null);
       if(res != null)
       {
           res.moveToFirst();
           chosen[0] = res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex(DIARY_COLUMN_N1));


       }
    return chosen;}
```

Comment: please post the logcat

Comment: what is the type of `DIARY_COLUMN_N1` ?

Comment: @thesma please post exception.

Comment: @thesma `getInt()` will throw `SQLException - if the columnIndex is not valid;`

Comment: DIARY_COLUMN_N1 is of type integer

Comment: chosen[0]  = (Integer)res.getColumnIndex(DIARY_COLUMN_N1)

Comment: Could you please post your TABLE CREATION code?

Comment: There are so many ways there can be a crashworthy problem here. "Not working" is not a way to describe one.

Comment: @thesma: dont use "select * from" if you only need one specific field. Please add table-description

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a *absolute need* to retrieve *all* the columns, you should not be doing so. There are precious few use cases where you *should* do that (such as a DB dump program).

So I would rewrite the query to just get the column you're interested in, then use:

```
res.getInt(0);
```

And, if you *still* have the same issue, you could probably also use `res.getType(0)` to *confirm* it's of `FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER`, since it seems your contention that the column is an integer may not be correct. Even if the type *is* integer, a `NULL` value in there will give you `FIELD_TYPE_NULL` rather than `FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER`.

Answer (score 0):

Match the datatype of your code and the db coloumn. It seems that your coloumn is varchar and you are trying to get it as int

Answer (score -1):

Cast the return statement...

```
(Integer)res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex(DIARY_COLUMN_N1));
```

Comment: Doesn't `getInt` return an `int`? What is the point of casting it (unless I'm mistaken - it wouldn't be the first time).